# What fields in exif files provide image Height/Width information

Tags: images

I am writing a simple(??) VB6 program to change a selected file's name.  I want to show a small(appx scaled to a 2"X3" ) image of the picture.  To avoid distortion of the image (I have to use a VB picture image) I want to alter the height and width of the displayed picture box to fit the size of the picture.  To do this I want to extract the height and width of the file, then ratio it down and resize the picture boxes size

Answer (score 3):

#### What fields in exif files provide image Height/Width information?

Here are the relevant Exif tags as defined in the [Exif 2.3 standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) (PDF Link):

```
+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Tag (hex)  | Tag (dec)  |  IFD   |          Key            | Type  |                                                                Tag description                                                                 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x0100     |       256  | Image  | Exif.Image.ImageWidth   | Long  | The number of columns of image data, equal to the number of pixels per row. In JPEG compressed data a JPEG marker is used instead of this tag. |
| 0x0101     |       257  | Image  | Exif.Image.ImageLength  | Long  | The number of rows of image data. In JPEG compressed data a JPEG marker is used instead of this tag.                                           |
+------------+------------+--------+-------------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Source [Standard Exif Tags](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html)